# Xamarin: Sizing Issues when dynamically adding rows to a Grid

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am new to Xamarin and I'm trying to figure out some of the basic functionality.

I have a simple content page containing a ScrollView with a nested StackLayout, then other nested controls within the StackLayout:

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="TestApp.Views.ScrollGrow">

  <ScrollView x:Name="myScrollView" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <StackLayout x:Name="MainStack" BackgroundColor="YellowGreen" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Label Text="Start of StackLayout"></Label>
        <Button Text="Populate Grid" Clicked="Button_Clicked" x:Name="btnFill" BackgroundColor="Black" TextColor="White"></Button>
        <Grid x:Name="myGrid" BackgroundColor="Yellow" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Grid>
        <Label Text="Bottom of StackLayout"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

I am attempting to dynamically add rows to the Grid on a button click:

```cs
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace TestApp.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class ScrollGrow : ContentPage
{

    public ScrollGrow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 35; i++)
            {
                FillMyGrid(i);
            }               
        });
    }

    private void FillMyGrid(int theCounter)
    {
        myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = GridLength.Auto, });
        var testLabel = new Label();
        testLabel.Text = "Test row number: " + theCounter;
        testLabel.TextColor = Color.Black;
        Grid.SetRow(testLabel, theCounter);
        Grid.SetColumn(testLabel, 0);
        myGrid.Children.Add(testLabel);
    }

  }
}
```

Unfortunately, the size of the StackLayout doesn't appear grow when the Grid grows.

| Before | After |
| --- | --- |
| [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUbnz.jpg] | [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5Syc.jpg] |

What am I missing here? Can someone explain to me why this isn't working and what the correct way to do this would be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using StackLayout outside of ScrollView may achieve the effect you want.

Here is the xaml code:

```
<StackLayout>
    <ScrollView x:Name="myScrollView" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <StackLayout x:Name="MainStack" BackgroundColor="YellowGreen" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Label Text="Start of StackLayout"></Label>
            <Button Text="Populate Grid" Clicked="btnFill_Clicked"  x:Name="btnFill" BackgroundColor="Black" TextColor="White"></Button>
            <Grid x:Name="myGrid" BackgroundColor="Yellow" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Grid>
            <Label Text="Bottom of StackLayout"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</StackLayout>
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Do you have any other questions

Comment: What would you say are the most common design mistakes that new Xamarin developers make?

Comment: Following the examples provided by Microsoft can effectively avoid most of the problems.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest rearranging your UI like this (using a `Grid`).

```xml
<Grid BackgroundColor="YellowGreen">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="Start of StackLayout"></Label>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Text="Populate Grid" Clicked="Button_Clicked" x:Name="btnFill" BackgroundColor="Black" TextColor="White"></Button>

    <ScrollView Grid.Row="2">
        <Grid x:Name="myGrid" BackgroundColor="Yellow"></Grid>
    </ScrollView>

    <Label Grid.Row="3" Text="Bottom of StackLayout"></Label>
</Grid>
```

Also, to show repetitive data it is better to use a [`ListView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/).

Comment: Thank you! I will look into switching to a ListView.

Answer (score 0):

StackLayouts can be a little confusing. For a child of a StackLayout with Orientation of Vertical, any requests for expansion (i.e. `VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"`) will be ignored because the StackLayout itself is determining the size of each child and thus the size of itself as the sum of all children plus any spacing and padding.

[As Hadi also suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69108471/16283948), it is better to use a ListView when showing repetitive data. I would also encourage you to use `Auto` very sparingly with Grids because of the additional burden of computing row heights on layout changes. If you'd prefer to continue using a Grid, I would suggest either using `*` (star) units for your rows to ensure they all size relative to each other, or setting a static row height which will then bubble up to the StackLayout's computed height.

Comment: Thanks for the info and detailed explanation!